# How to set Parameters for Titanium.Yahoo.YQL?

Tags: oauth, titanium-mobile, yql, yahoo-oauth

I cant find anyway to put parameters into YQL to fetch private data like contacts lists etc.I dont find it documented anywhere..

I know we can fetch public data without parameters but i am asking about private data which needs parameters like `oauth_token` and `oauth_signature` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Made my own alternative.It fetches Yahoo,MSN,Google Contacts for now.

[**`OAuth_social`**](https://github.com/Nezam/oauth_social)